# Reinventing The Wheel: Random Number Generator

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, numbers, seed

So I'm new to C++ and am trying to learn some things. As such I am trying to make a Random Number Generator (RNG or PRNG if you will). I have basic knowledge of RNGs, like you have to start with a seed and then send the seed through the algorithm. What I'm stuck at is how people come up with said algorithms.

Here is the code I have to get the seed.

```
int getSeed()
{
    time_t randSeed;
    randSeed = time(NULL);
    return randSeed;
}
```

Now I know that there is are prebuilt RNGs in C++ but I'm looking to learn not just copy other people's work and try to figure it out.

So if anyone could lead me to where I could read or show me examples of how to come up with algorithms for this I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Have you read this article? http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generation.html

Comment: The design of PRNG is language-agnostic and has more to do with number theory and algebra than programming. If your goal is to learn C++ with some examples, you should look for something different. If you want to understand PRNG design you should remove the parts mentioning C++.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie I have read that article but I couldn't really make heads or tails as to what it was trying to say.

Comment: @Simon Stelling Well it goes both ways, I guess I should have mentioned that in the first post. I am trying to learn not only C++ but also concepts behind basic programming. Random Number Generation being one of those basic concepts.

Comment: @Cistoran: Understanding what makes a good RNG requires a great deal of knowledge of mathematics; statistics, number theory, group theory, etc. (most of which is beyond my knowledge and patience level).  It's not the sort of thing I'd recommend you casually get into.  There are far more worthwhile things to learn, given that, as you say, it would be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Have you read [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) on the subject?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Point taken, at this point I'm not looking for anything fantastic like a Mersenne Twister or the like, merely a simple algorithm that I could plug a seed (as seen above) into and get a (fairly) random number out of.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I have, but as I told Seth, I'm not very far along as far as education goes and can't really distinguish what I should be doing when I'm reading all of it.

Comment: as I see from your code, you're thinking about using time as a source of random data.
you can use functions in sys/time.h and device any computation that combine timestamp fields together to produce a random number which wont be a uniformly distributed number.

Comment: A couple people have slightly discouraged this pursuit. I say go for it. Whatever area interests you, follow it. Don't let people saying it's not practical bother you - it may not be practical, but it should be educational. Random numbers will lead you into areas many programmers never visit - bit twiddling, number theory, statistics - all worth learning about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, just to clarify, any algorithm you come up with will be a pseudo random number generator and not a true random number generator.  Since you would be making an algorithm (i.e. writing a function, i.e. making a set of rules), the random number generator would have to eventually repeat itself or do something similar which would be non-random.

Examples of truly random number generators are one's that capture random noise from nature and digitize it.  These include:

http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/

http://www.random.org/

You can also buy physical equipment that generate white noise (or some other means on randomness) and digitally capture it:

http://www.lavarnd.org/

http://www.idquantique.com/true-random-number-generator/products-overview.html

http://www.araneus.fi/products-alea-eng.html

In terms of pseudo random number generators, the easiest ones to learn (and ones that an average lay person could probably make on their own) are the [linear congruential generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).  Unfortunately, these are also some of the worst PRNGs there are.

Some guidelines for determining what is a good PRNG include:

1. Periodicity (what is the range of available numbers?)
2. Consecutive numbers (what is the probability that the same number will be repeated twice in a row)
3. Uniformity (Is it just as likely to pick numbers from a certain sub range as another sub range)
4. Difficulty in reverse engineering it (If it is close to truly random then someone should not be able to figure out the next number it generates based on the last few numbers it generated)
5. Speed (how fast can I generate a new number? Does it take 5 or 500 arithmetic operations)
6. I'm sure there are others I am missing

One of the more popular ones right now that is considered good in most applications (ie not crptography) is the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister).  As you can see from the link, it is a simple algorithm, perhaps only 30 lines of code.  However trying to come up with those 20 or 30 lines of code from scratch takes a lot of brainpower and study of PRNGs.  Usually the most famous algorithms are designed by a professor or industry professional that has studied PRNGs for decades.

I hope you do study PRNGs and try to roll your own (try Knuth's Art of Computer Programming or Numerical Recipes as a starting place), but I just wanted to lay this all out so at the end of the day (unless PRNGs will be your life's work) its much better to just use something someone else has come up with.  Also, along those lines, I'd like to point out that historically compilers, spreadsheets, etc. don't use what most mathematicians consider good PRNGs so if you have a need for a high quality PRNGs don't use the standard library one in C++, Excel, .NET, Java, etc. until you have research what they are implementing it with.

Comment: Re "Difficulty in reverse engineering it": That's a concern for cryptographically secure PRNGs, but not for PRNGs in general. A typical use of a PRNG is to add a bit of randomness to a computer game or to a Monte Carlo simulation. There's no need here for a secure PRNG for such applications. OTOH, if you are using a PRNG to encrypt a message or a digital signature, then concerns about reverse engineering rise to the forefront.

Answer (score 3):

A linear congruential generator is commonly used and the [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) explains it pretty well.

Comment: Not really.  In particular, it says "The most efficient LCGs have an m equal to a power of 2, most often m = 2^32 or m = 2^64."  It has been proven that you cannot get a good generator when `m` is a power of two; `m` should be prime.  The reference for linear congruential generators is "Random Number Generators: Good Ones Are Hard to Find", Park and Miller, CACM Oct. 1988.

Comment: @James The marvelous thing about Wikipedia is that it's users like you who can edit and improve it. Also, note it says 'efficient', not 'good'. If you want a good PRNG, you shouldn't be using an LCG at all.

Answer (score 3):

To quote John von Neumann:

> Anyone who considers arithmetical
>   methods of producing random digits is
>   of course in a state of sin.

This is taken from **Chapter 3 Random Numbers** of Knuth's book "The Art of Computer Programming", which must be the most exhaustive overview of the subject available. And once you have read it, you will be exhausted. You will also know why you don't want to write your own random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution best fulfills the requirements and the requirements of every situation will be unique. This is probably the simplest way to go about it:

- Create a large one dimensional array
  populated with "real" random values.
- "seed" your pseudo-random generator by
  calculating the starting index with
  system time.
- Iterate through the array and return
  the value for each call to your
  function.
- Wrap around when it reaches the end.